# How get the a static resource value at DesignTime in MarkupExtension?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

I Succeeded in Creating my own MarkupExtension i named it "GtringResource" and it is working well, but in design mode didn't.

I have the following code in ProvideValue(IServieProvider ServiceProvider):

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
        if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new  DependencyObject()))
        {

            return "design mode";
        }

        StaticResourceExtension staticResourceExtension = new StaticResourceExtension(this.GtringKey);
        var gtringresource = staticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) as Gtring;            
        return gtringresource.en;
}
```

I want to return the value that should appear at runtime cause i retrieve the value from  a merged dictionary, looks like in xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="downloadButton"  Content="{intllectual:GtringResource downloadGtring}"/>
```

I tried this but it is not helpful:

```
/// ... when detect desingmode "IsDesingMode"
return ((Gtring)Application.Current.TryFindResource(GtringKey)).en;
/// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public class ResourceExtension : StaticExtension
```

Comment: This is too short to be helpful. I'm not really sure what Johan is suggesting.

Comment: I'm not sure either coming back to this. Maybe a different service provider is provided at designtime if subclassing `StaticExtension`?